# Borel sigma algebra coming from the weak topology on TVS

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, borel-sets

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space. Suppose that, there is a sequence of subsets $X_n\subseteq X$ with,

1. For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the topology  $\tau$ on $X_n$ is  second countable and metrizable space.
2. $X_n\subseteq X_{n+1}$ and $X=\bigcup X_n$.

Q. Is the Borel sigma algebra coming from the weak topology  $\sigma(X,X^*)$ is the same as the Borel sigma algebra coning from $\tau$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are separable metric TVS $X$ whose topological dual is trivial (one example is $L_p([0,1])$ for $0\le p<1$). Such $X$ satisfies 1 and 2 (w.r.to the sequence $X_n:=X$), and the two sigma algebras are of course not the same.

Comment: So for a positive result I think one should assume at least e.g. $X$ to be locally convex, and the $X_n$ linear subspaces.

Comment: Great example, thanks a lot.